# "Post has been edited" banner keeps coming back after being dismissed

Tags: bug, edits, live-refresh, notification-bar

When a post is edited while I'm editing it (usually a bad suggested edit going through in my despite, but not always), the banner that comes up is annoying enough to see *once*. But if I've checked it out and determined that yes, I do in fact wish to continue editing, hitting the Close button should **leave it gone and closed and *trouble me no longer***.

But such is apparently not the case! Just now I had the same banner come back for the same edit three times. And as far as I can tell, there [weren't any new changes within the grace period](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30135533/revisions#rev7e35fc35-52c9-4786-8c9c-392d4b9008d5), either: it began and finished as a simple removal of a few lines to disable that horrible Stack Snippets misuse. (Doubting myself a bit, I double-checked with a few suggested edits, opening revisions page every time the banner re-appeared like clockwork: [neither](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12901477/revisions#rev5d05831b-8044-4d40-b69d-c04c948cbfc8) had [any new changes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30135645/revisions#reva0137ba4-3690-4dab-bdb8-de7fc8be7bbf) discernible at any time.)

Comment: The way you describe it, it's a bug - the live refresh timer doesn't take into account your actions.